# BIDS 2008 DTS package remove password

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2008, bids

I have an old SSIS project that I need to open due to some failures in production, but it's password protected. I think I know the password, but I can't find a way to enter it. There's no prompt window, dialog, nothing at all. Just the error "DTS:Password" protected: 0x8009000B "invalid password".

If possible, I'd like to remove the password since it has no use, I can't find a way to change the protection level since I can't open the package at all. I'm using a VS2008 shell to open it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have access to the VS solution/project files?

Comment: Yes! But every time I try to open the solution with BIDS I encounter the same issue.